# Why does my variable lose its value?

Tags: c#, asp.net

From the `selectedindexchanged` event, my variable has a value, but when it reaches the `btn_click()` event, the variable no longer has a value. Why is that?

```
public partial class TestingDatapass
{
  private string item = null;
  private string itemprice = null;
  private int totalprice = 0;

  protected void item_selectedindexchanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      //Both have a value here
      item = item.SelectedValue;
      itemprice = item.SelectedValue.Text;
  }

  protected void btn_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      //no value here
      totalprice = Convert.ToInt32(itemprice)*Convert.ToInt32(item);
      MessageBox.Show(totalprice);
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
And to answer the ? posed in comments, the order of occurrence is the `selectedindexchange` THEN the `btn_click()`
**EDIT REGARDING View State**
So then would this be a proper way to set up what I am trying to achieve?

```
public partial class TestingDatapass
{
    private int totalprice = 0;

  protected void item_selectedindexchanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      ViewState["item"] = item.SelectedValue;
      ViewState["itemprice"] = item.SelectedValue.Text;
  }

  protected void btn_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      totalprice = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["item"])*Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["itemprice"]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Seems like the `btw_click`  is handled before the `item_selectedindexchanged`. A while since I've done ASP.Net but we had that problem - event handling order is not guaranteed. In one case we had many events and the only way to make things work was to have a single method as the handler. This method re-calculated the state of the entire page, every time.

Comment: are both called in the same request?

Comment: No - the selected index change is occuring THEN the button press event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a page is requested, ASP.NET creates an instance of `TestingDatapass` class and initialize `itemprice`,`totalprice` etc. fields. Now when you change your dropdown from client (which I assume looking at your `item_selectedindexchanged` method), Postback happens and it assign values you have mentioned in `item_selectedindexchanged`. Finally it destroys the instance, generates the html and sends it back to browser.

Now, when you press the button in your page then a new instance is created, your fields are re-initialized and you don't see the changed values in `btn_click`. This is how it works.

Thus if you want to preserve any data across postback, Consider using any [State Management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx) technique like `ViewState, HiddenField` etc.

Also, as a side note, `MessageBox.Show` is not available in ASP.NET.

**Update:**

I answered in the context of why it is not retaining the value in button click event, there are many ways to do it. But to answer your question, I don't see any reason to store the values in `item_selectedindexchanged` event as you are not doing anything there. You can directly access the dropdown selected values in button click handler like this:-

```
protected void btn_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      totalprice = Convert.ToInt32(item.SelectedValue) * 
                   Convert.ToInt32(item.SelectedItem.Text);
  }
```

Also, please note it's `item.SelectedItem.Text` and not `SelectedValue.Text`.

Comment: see my edit, would that be an appropriate way of achieving my desired result?

Comment: @MustangLover - You can but that's not required, check my update.

Comment: I must err in my syntax somewhere as when I try it the way you suggested it hits the totalprice line and throws error 'Input Value is not in the correct format'

Comment: @MustangLover - Hey based on your code I assumed both dropdown text and value are `integers` but I guess it's not so it is giving that error.

Comment: will I still need to use the SelectedIndexChange if I am going to calculate in the btn_Click event like you posted (and is much easier!)

Comment: @MustangLover - No that's what I said, if you are not doing anything when you are changing your dropdown then it's not required.